# Linking SubReports Without LinkChild/LinkMaster

Tags: ms-access

I'm maintaining and occasionally modifying an Access 97 program that's still a crucial department tool for a very large US corporation.

A number of reports use a "totals" subreport that I cannot link using LinkChildFields \ LinkMasterFields. In each case, the main report can be filtered by numerous (or no) criteria via a "Reports Manager" form.

I've coped with this by using a generic function that opens any subreport in design view, and edits the .Filter property. Works 100% OK.

However, this prevents me from distributing the app as an .mde file, as Design view is unavailable in an mde.

I've tried every alternative I can think of:

- setting the subform filter during Open event to that of the Parent (error)
- using Docmd.ApplyFilter during Open event (does nothing at all in a subform)

Although this 'old' app suits the Department using it perfectly, their IT want to implement a 'big-picture solution', and I really don't want a competitor to have free access to a heck of a lot of complex business rules I've worked so hard on over the years.

Does anyone have any suggestions re the subform filtering, so I can use an mde?

MTIA

Comment: Have you tried changing the recordsource in the OnOpen event of the child subreport? You'd have to have either controls in the parent form with the values you're filtering on or global variables to pull the values from, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks David. Its a variation of Remou's suggestion, but has the advantage of not altering the underlying query. I'll try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered rewriting a query on which the subreport is based? The SQL string of a query is easy to change, and you will be able to make an mde using this method.

Comment: Thanks Remou, this turned out to be the best 'generic' solution!

Answer (score 6):

Why can't you link to the "totals" subreport using Link Child/Master? It should run off the same record source as the main report and aggregate over the records. In any case, if you can specify a filter criteria, you should be able to specify a [domain aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168244%28office.10%29.aspx) criteria (dsum, dcount, dlookup etc) that returns the same values.

Dynamically editing the filter property in design view to make it work is a kludge. There is a reason that it difficult, not because the Access designers wanted to make it hard for you to embed subreports with dynamic criteria, but because it's a bad idea. Don't do it. There is something wrong with your report record source if you can't either join the subreport on record fields, or get rid of the subreport altogether and [aggregate within the main report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208850). You probably already know this, but you can aggregate (sum, count, etc) over the detail in a report in the report/page/group header/footer and give totals that way.

For example, if you were writing a report for a printable invoice, you could move everything above the line items into the report header, leave a line item as the report detail, and move everything below the line items into the report footer. Then you could do `sum()` over the detail fields to generate your subtotal then add tax, shipping etc. Another way to do this would be to use a subreport for the line items then try to calculate the totals externally, not as simple and way more fragile if the subreport changes.

Comment: The main report groups at a number of levels, then shows details. The subreport also groups, but at the highest couple of levels only, with no detail. Its kind of a one page 'summary' at the end of the main report. Thus it doesn't lend itself to the 'normal' aggregation functions.
Each group could be the subject of a filter, thus the subreport has to use the same filters.

Comment: Arh, I see. How are the filters for the main report defined? In a 'choose the report you want to see' type filter form with picklists? Or do you open the report with a different filter or WHERE condition? You really only need to be able to reference the filter criteria in your subform the same way you can reference it in your main form. You could do this by using an absolute reference to a hidden 'filter criteria' field on the form (e.g. Form_MyFilterForm.MyReportCriteria ) where the user sets up the criteria, or reference the filter property of the main report directly.

Comment: Yes, my 'Reports manager' form allows users to select the criteria from any of a number of combos. The Preview & Print buttons reference a function which concatenates the required WHERE clause, and then opens the report using that. However, there may be no clause at all. A typical clause could be: "(region_id=2) AND (area_id=32) AND (subcontractor_id=397)" etc. Even if I saved that to a hidden field in the reports form, I can't see how I'd use that in the subreport's query?

Comment: I should mention that there are many reports, selectable from a listbox. The filters available for each report vary, so when a report is selected, only the relevant filter options are displayed. My previous method of filtering the subreport in design view allowed a generic function to apply whatever criteria was applicable for the main report.